# Wrong data populated in tableview cell on dispatch queue

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have an iOS app that has a UITableView with custom TableViewCells that contain a UIImageView.  The image is loaded from a web service, so during the initial load, I display a "loading" image, and then use gcd to dispatch and get the image matching the data for that cell.

When I use a DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH global queue to perform the image fetch, I sporadically get the wrong images loading in the tableview cells.  If I use my own custom queue then the correct images get populated into the cells but the tableview performance is awful.

Here is the code...

```
    // See if the icon is in the cache
if([self.photoCache objectForKey:[sample valueForKey:@"api_id"]]){
    [[cell sampleIcon]setImage:[self.photoCache objectForKey:[sample valueForKey:@"api_id"]]];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Cache miss");
        [cell.sampleIcon setImage:nil];
        dispatch_queue_t cacheMissQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cacheMissQueue", NULL);
        //dispatch_queue_t cacheMissQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(cacheMissQueue, ^{
            if(sample.thumbnailFilename && sample.api_id){
                NSData *thumbNailData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sample.thumbnailFilename];
                UIImage *thumbNailImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:thumbNailData];
                if(thumbNailImage){
                    // Set the cell
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [[cell sampleIcon]setImage:thumbNailImage];
                        [cell setNeedsLayout];
                    });
                    // save it to cache for future references
                    NSLog(@"DEBUG: Saving to cache %@ for sample %@",sample.thumbnailFilename,[sample objectID]);
                    [self.photoCache setObject:thumbNailImage forKey:sample.api_id];
                }
            }
        });
        dispatch_release(cacheMissQueue);
}
```

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to release the queue right after you dispatch an operation to it. It's going to go Create Queue -> Add operation to queue -> immediately release queue, regardless of if the operation has completed. Also if you create your own queue you shouldn't re-create it every time you run through cellForRowAtIndexPath. Create it once and then add multiple operations to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching the WWDC 2012 session #211 helped a lot and I changed the code from using GCD to NSOperationQueue and it solved the problem.

New code...

```
[[self imgQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
            if(sample.thumbnailFilename && sample.api_id){
                NSData *thumbNailData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:sample.thumbnailFilename];
                UIImage *thumbNailImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:thumbNailData];
                if(thumbNailImage){
                    // Set the cell
                    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
                        [[cell sampleIcon]setImage:thumbNailImage];
                        [cell setNeedsLayout];
                    }];
                    // save it to cache for future references
                    [self.photoCache setObject:thumbNailImage forKey:sample.api_id];
                }
            }

        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you finally get an image, you need an association between the indexPath of the cell and the image. Since this is on a backgound thread, what I suggest you do is post a nofification using a block to the mainQueue that such and such an image is available. On the main thread only, you ask the tableView for the array of visible cells, and if the cell you have an image for is showing, you can then set the image directly at that time (your on the main thread, you know the cell is there and showing, and its not going to change for this runloop iteration.) If the cell is not showing, no problem, next time that cell comes into scope you will have the image waiting for it. I am doing this now in my app, its been out many months, and its all working well and getting good reviews on responsiveness (just as your app will if you do this!)